# Advantage and Disadvantage of N2CMS

Tags: n2cms

I am currently gathering knowledge on various CMS option's available for .Net(free/open-source).

I came across **DotNetNuke** and **N2CMS**.

Was just wandering thru the source code of n2cms and found it quiet useful.

Even thought i don't have much idea about the disadvantage's .

Please let me know, if any one of you have worked on n2cms and can let me know the disadvantage and any other OPEN SOURCE CMS option's available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disadvantages of N2CMS:

- It does not "feel" like an enterprise-level app, it feels a lot lighter. That's not to say it's not up for a match at that level, but I think it says more about the clever implementation which hides away a lot of the complexity. Note that N2CMS is not a 2+-tiered application, but it looks like there's a recent branch exploring the loading of data from other places (like from an extra tier).
- This brings in another disadvantage: it's documentation leaves a lot to be desired. This is due to the small *active* community and the quickly evolving code. So you'll have a lot of code digging ahead if you want to take full advantage of the ultra-flexible N2CMS. Mind too that the maintainer (libardo) is a very quick responder, both for technical assistance as for bug fixing!
- Persistence happens with only 4 tables (if that still holds). "Regular" DB optimization might therefore be impossible. Otoh, premature optimzation is the root of all evil, and on top of that, because you're dealing with NHibernate, you can pull some tricks on that level.
- I'm afraid that while still small, Orchard - a somewhat comparable CMS - might catch up on N2CMS, because it has some large players behind it who attract community. Either N2CMS will have to walk an equally "commercial" route, or it is going to be surpassed by Orchard at some time. Having created some NuGet packages was a very good step in that regard!

My take on N2 is that it's one of the best CMS's around for developers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Umbraco, its architecture is definitely better than DNN's. DNN is an abomination from hell. Most end users hate it with a passion.

I like N2CMS, but it's a often a hard sell because the community around it isn't really big...

Answer (score 0):

Advantage of N2CMS:

- Editing User Experience / Preview Funtionallity - I can navigate the site via it's [frontend] menus, and the cms tree on the left will be synced instantly. Or if the backend is closed, i have a small toolbar that allows to edit the a page immediately or to open the backend right where i am.

This is for me also the most important feature N2CMS has and Umbraco is missing.